# How to copy the value of datagrid column easyui

Tags: javascript, jquery-easyui, zeroclipboard

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tbIndex = undefined
    var tbData = undefined

    $('#dg').datagrid({
        onClickRow:function(rowIndex,rowData){
            tbIndex = rowIndex
            tbData = rowData
        },
        onClickCell:function(rowIndex,field,value)
        {
            if(field == 'type' || field == 'name' || field == 'card' || field == 'money')
            {
                var t = $('#dg').datagrid('selectRow',rowIndex)
                console.log($(t).html())
                ZeroClipboard.config({moviePath: "{{ URL::to('/') }}/images/ZeroClipboard.swf"})
                //copy contents()
                var client = new ZeroClipboard($('#dg').datagrid('selectRow',rowIndex));

                client.on( 'load', function(client) {
                    //alert( "movie is loaded" );
                    client.on( 'datarequested', function(client) {
                        client.setText(this.innerHTML);
                    } );

                    client.on( 'complete', function(client, args) {
                        alert("copy complete:" + args.text );
                    } );

                } );
            }

        }
    })
```

I now want to implement click a column, copy the contents of a column

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could do something like

```
$('#dg').datagrid({
    onClickCell:function(rowIndex,field,value) {
         var rows = $('#dg').datagrid('getRows');
         var results = [];
         for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
             if (field == 'type') {
                results[i] = rows[i].type;
             } else if (field == 'name') {
                results[i] = rows[i].name;
             } else if (field == 'card') {
                results[i] = rows[i].card;
             } else if (field == 'money') {
                results[i] = rows[i].money;
             }
         }
    }
});
```

This will get you the values of rows of the same column as the cell you clicked.